# Xamarin Android: How do i pass variables to a buttons event method in ExpandableListView?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an ExpandableListView with buttons in it's child-view. I want to bind event handler with button's click.

this is what I want to achieve:

```html
public void func1()
{
    // let say we have following arguments
    int arg1= 100;          
    SomeObject arg2 = new SomeObj("John", "1000");
    button.Click -= DeleteActionHandler;
    button.Click += DeleteActionHandler;     // this is point-1
}
```

### DeleteActionHandler is as:

```html
void DeleteActionHandler(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   // some implementation
   // I want  arg1 and arg2 to be passed here.
}
```

The question is I want to pass some arguments in DeleteActionHandler from point-1. Can I send arguments in EventArgs?? or is there any other way.

Comment: Do you use `MVVM` and bind buttons to `ICommand`?

Comment: No, no using MVVM and can't bind to ICommand.

Comment: Question is very much clear though but I have edited to make it more clear. Please try to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass data to `DeleteActionHandler` directly. However, you can use a `Tag` property of a `button` to set data and read it later in `DeleteActionHandler` like this `((Button)sender).Tag`.

Here is a piece of code base on your code sample:

```
public void func1()
{
    ...
    button.Tag = new ParametersWrapper(arg1, arg2);
}

void DeleteActionHandler(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   var args = (ParametersWrapper)((Button)sender).Tag;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this will clear you more.

Comment: Hay, Can I use extended class of EventArgs. How can I use it. Can you guide. For example I have class as------ public class ExtendedClass: EventArgs {  // property1 and property2 }. How can I use it on click event.

Comment: Because `Click` event is fired by a system, you cannot modify `EventArgs` which is sent to `DeleteActionHandler`.

Comment: So, is there any solution to achieve the functionality??

Comment: It's still in the answer, I've extended it with code sample

Comment: One more thing please. Is ParametersWrapper predefined class or should I create it. Sorry for sill question but I need to clear it.

Comment: Nope, there is no such predefined class. However, if you have to pass parameters of different types in several places and don't want to create `ParametersWrapper` of different kinds, you can get away with `Tuple`: `Tuple<int, SomeObject>` in this particular case.

Comment: Thankyou Very Much. Foxanna You are awesome.

Comment: You are welcome. My advice for the future would be to bind a `Button` to an `ICommand`, this would facilitate the task for you.

Answer (score 3):

Pass variable to a button event method in xamarin.forms using xamarin studio , please see below example..

Example

```
public partial class StackOverflowTest : ContentPage
{
    public StackOverflowTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string strvalue = "Delete";
        BtnTest.Clicked += delegate (object sender2, EventArgs e2)
        {
            DeleteActionHandler(sender2, e2, strvalue);
        };
    }

    private void DeleteActionHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string strval)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Greeting", $"{strval}!", "Ok");
    }

}
```